# Factors limiting MILP solver calculation speed?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am fairly new to Mixed Integer Linear Programming and I was hoping someone could clarify a performance question for me. Basically I am performing a calculation with about 34 decision variables and my calculation time is around 5 seconds. I would like to ideally get the calculation time down into the sub 1 second range.

Currently I am using the CBC solver & MATLAB, but as I understand it this is a single-threaded solver. Most of the MILP solvers I've seen seem to pride themselves on large project performance with 1k+ variables and knocking compute time down from days to hours but only a few of the expensive ones are even multi-threaded. Processor speed would seem to only go so far with such a problem so there has to be something that could be done on the software side.

In a situation like I have what factors play a role in the calculation time? In theory would a solution like Gurobi be able to ramp up and make a discernible difference over CBC on such a small problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your 5 second time is not spent mostly with some kind of overhead from MATLAB? Usually, very small problems should be solved in less than 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I think the way it is setup currently there is a fair amount of overhead just loading and unloading the CBC solver. I am switching it to the native MILP solver in MATLAB and going to see if tuning that method can cut down the run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When solving MIPs, multi-threading usually doesn't help that much, compared to other applications. One thing more sophisticated solvers do better than CBC is presolving. It may very well happen, that all decision variables can be eliminated/fixed in the root node. In general, it is not possible to predict the solving time of a MIP based on its size. The solving process is simply too complex.
To answer your question: I do suppose that you will see a significant speedup when trying another solver (Gurobi, Xpress, CPLEX, SCIP, etc.). It is not guaranteed though, and you might also witness a slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the commercial MILP solvers would probably consider most problems with only 1000 variables to be tiny. It is very common to solve problems with hundreds of thousands or millions of variables. Note however, that there are also some really small problems that are considered to be very hard or still open in that nobody has solved them to a proven optimal solution. Basically, the time taken to solve these problems is enormously problem dependent.

If you want to see how fast another solver can solve your problem, try submitting it as e.g. an MPS file to the NEOS solver service at http://www.neos-server.org/neos/